# Include independent local library to my android app with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

I am having a hard time including a local library as a dependency of my android app using gradle.

The main reason is due to the fact that this library is an independent library outside of the project where my android app is.

From what I understood, this could be done using [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). So I was trying to use it.

I created a very small repo to illustrate my problem: https://github.com/ampeixoto/composite-build-example

Basically I want to add `:my-external-lib` as a dependency of `:app` module

So I added `includeBuild '../my-external-lib'` into the `my-composite-app\settings.gradle`.

So far, if I sync gradle, I can now see the `my-external-lib` in the project structure.

But when I try to add the dependency to the `app\build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {

    //Trying to add the dependency to my lib here
    implementation project(":my-external-lib")

    //other dependencies
}
```

I get the following error when synching gradle:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':my-external-lib' could not be found in project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.project(DefaultProject.java:659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:135)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:77)
    at build_4wxxt4nomiqq4pt98j577hegv$_run_closure2.doCall(C:\Projects\CompositeBuildExample\my-composite-app\app\build.gradle:42)
```

I feel I am missing something simple, but not sure what... Any pointer will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. Need to add a `group 'com.example'` on the `my-external-lib\build.gradle` and then I can add the dependency like using:

```
implementation "com.example:my-external-lib"
```

See [commit](https://github.com/ampeixoto/composite-build-example/commit/22e8b1048aa227dbd1b9fac87d7a70bb95e8d3ae) with the fix.

Comment: This was half of the solution for me.  

Additionally in my project we publish the lib to maven, but the Artifact Id that I publish to did not match the enclosing folder name.  In addition to the group I also had to change subproject name in the top level settings.gradle file: `project(":folder-name").name = "actual-artifact-name"`